# np.array_equal true element wise but not tottally

Tags: python, numpy

So I have two arrays a and b, that represent weights from layers of two separate but supposedly same models. If I do:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i, a[i].shape)
...
for i in range(len(b)):
    print(i, b[i].shape)
```

I get the same results, therefore they are of the exact same shape. Given that, I do:

```
 for i in range(len(a)):
    print(np.array_equal(a[i],b[i]))
```

Which returns True in every iteration, as expected. 
And yet:

```
np.array_equal(a,b)
False
```

What explains that?

Note: the arrays are in the millions of element so I can't have them here

---

Edit: Additional info requested.
I've tried `np.allcose(a,b)` but it returns error : `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types,`.

Other info:

```
a.dtype
Out[31]: dtype('O')

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i].dtype)

float32
..
float32
```

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i].shape)

(8, 8, 4, 32)
(32,)
(4, 4, 32, 64)
(64,)
(3, 3, 64, 64)
(64,)
(3136, 512)
(512,)
(512, 7)
(7,)
```

Typical values , eg. after typing `a` at the console:

```
array([[ 0.07951447, -0.05771456,  0.19115011, ...,  0.00221113,
        -0.07151963, -0.043664  ],
       [-0.12819108, -0.35420918, -0.2011751 , ..., -0.17197789,
        -0.3776419 ,  0.0248649 ],
       [ 0.14795731, -0.00116287, -0.11165092, ...,  0.05597401,
         0.10254459, -0.05197995],
       ...,
       [-0.02236149, -0.00130034,  0.08647525, ..., -0.05736822,
         0.0443062 ,  0.10795061],
       [-0.06922315, -0.16868076,  0.09703451, ...,  0.06901634,
         0.09876721,  0.0513133 ],
       [-0.02136025,  0.04748438,  0.1370429 , ..., -0.09078182,
        -0.08319436, -0.14710473]], dtype=float32),
       array([-0.25613004, -0.19301122, -0.23552935,  0.11345425, -0.23320739,
       -0.18501312,  0.13193467], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

Everything is the exact same for `b`

Comment: are you comparing floats?

Comment: Yes, numpy.float32. Why / How would that create problems?

Comment: Because of rounding diffences, `==` tests on floats are unreliable.  `np.allclose` is better, since it tests for differences with a certain rounding tolerance.

Comment: @hpaulj that doesn't explain why checking on each element returns `True` for all elements. But then again, `np.allclose` might be a better choice.

Comment: np.allcose(a,b) returns "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types,". Is that perhaps the problem that makes a and b 'unequal'

Comment: Tell us more about `a` and `b`.  Especially `dtype` (and `shape`).  What are the typical values?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You've got an array of arrays. Making those is almost never a good idea, and this is only one of the many ways in which they don't behave like you would expect.